# [Content_Types].xml <Override> element missing

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a 2007+ Excel document (.xlsx), using nothing but **.net 4.0 built-in classes**.
So I **can't use any third party libraries**.

Actually it's done for the most part, the only problem I'm facing now is that, the package I'm creating seems to fail on the creation of the **[Content_Types].xml** file, I mean it lacks all the **<Override>** elements, and only the **<Default>** elements are created.

I'm pretty sure the problem is at the point where I create the relationships between the packages, but I just don't know how to make it work, and documentation and examples on **Package** and **ZipPackage** classes are surprisingly scarce.

Maybe I'm missing another step...does some one has any clue? please

This is a similar code which produces excactly the same problem

```
public void CreatePackage()
        {
            string Dir = @"F:\Proyectos\Excel_StackOverflow\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Resources";

        Uri File1_abs = new Uri(String.Format(@"{0}\1.xml", Dir), UriKind.Absolute);
                Uri File1_rel = new Uri(@"/OddContent/File1.xml", UriKind.Relative);

                using (ZipPackage exPkg = (ZipPackage)Package.Open(String.Format(@"{0}\Temp.zip", Dir), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    ZipPackagePart File1Part = (ZipPackagePart)exPkg.CreatePart(File1_rel, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml);
                    using (FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(File1_abs.LocalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        Form1.CopyStream(fs1, File1Part.GetStream());
                    }
                    exPkg.CreateRelationship(File1_rel, TargetMode.Internal, "SomeType");
                    exPkg.Flush();
                    exPkg.Close();
                    }
            }

        private static void CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)
        {
            const int bufSize = 0x1000;
            byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buf, 0, bufSize)) > 0)
                target.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
```

and the [Content_Types].xml file it generates for the given code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
<Default ContentType="text/xml" Extension="xml"/>
</Types>
```

But actually I'm expecting something like this to be the [Content_Types].xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
<Default ContentType="text/xml" Extension="xml"/>
<Override PartName="...................."/>
</Types>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Override" element will be put into the types list, once there is a part that is stored with the default extension but a different Content Type.

Here's an updated version that will create the "Override" element for the File1Part:

```
        Uri File1_rel = new Uri(@"/OddContent/File1.xml", UriKind.Relative);
        Uri File2_rel = new Uri(@"/OddContent/File2.xml", UriKind.Relative);

        using (ZipPackage exPkg = (ZipPackage)Package.Open(String.Format(@"{0}\Temp.zip", Dir), FileMode.Create))
        {
            ZipPackagePart p2 = (ZipPackagePart)exPkg.CreatePart(File2_rel, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml);
            ZipPackagePart File1Part = (ZipPackagePart)exPkg.CreatePart(File1_rel, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.documents.main+xml");
```

NOTE: I type-copied the mime type for the vnd... from an image, it might have typos, feel free to fix.

The created [Content_Types].xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
<Default Extension="xml" ContentType="text/xml" />
<Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" />
<Override PartName="/OddContent/File1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.documents.main+xml" />
</Types>
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, your answer was excellent, and saved my day, great!